# Plugin conflict error : Google plus and Push plugin

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap

I need to used google plus and push notification both but **Phonegap Build gives error** :

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the
>   google-services plugin (information about the latest version is
>   available at bintray.com/android/…) or updating the version of
>   com.google.android.gms to 11.6.2.

**index.html :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Device Ready Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="push.js"></script> 


    <script> 

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Now safe to use device APIs
        var push = PushNotification.init({
            "android": {
              "senderID": "xxxxxxxxxx"
            },
        });


    push.on('registration', function(data) {
        alert('registration event: ' + data.registrationId);
        console.log('registration event: ' + data.registrationId);

        var oldRegId = localStorage.getItem('registrationId');
        if (oldRegId !== data.registrationId) {
        // Save new registration ID
        localStorage.setItem('registrationId', data.registrationId);
        // Post registrationId to your app server as the value has changed
     }

    var parentElement = document.getElementById('registration');
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.waiting');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');
  });
}

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onLoad()">
  </body>
</html>
```

**config.xml :**

```
    <widget id="com.phonegap.notificationtest1" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
        <name>notificationtest1</name>
        <description>
         notificationtest1
        </description>
        <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
            sqlchild
        </author> 


            <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="17" /> 

            <preference name='phonegap-version' value='cli-8.0.0' />

            <preference name='pgb-builder-version' value='2' />



    <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="2.1.3">   
            <param name="SENDER_ID" value="xxxxxxxxxxxx" />
    </plugin> 


        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-googleplus" source="npm" spec="5.3.0"></plugin>  


        <platform name="android">   

            <resource-file src="app/google-services.json" target="app/google-services.json" />  

        </platform>      


        <content src="index.html" />
```

Comment: @DaveAlden : Hey Dave, can you let me know how to fork the plugin and use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cordova-plugin-googleplus` [currently pins v11.8.0](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/blob/master/plugin.xml#L32) of the Play Services library (`com.google.android.gms`).

`phonegap-plugin-push` [currently pins v11.6.2](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/plugin.xml#L42) of the Firebase library which in turn pins v11.6.2 of the Play Services Library.

Hence the conflicting versions of the Play Services library are causing your build error.

`phonegap-plugin-push` also now [depends](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/plugin.xml#L47) on [cordova-support-google-services](https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-support-google-services) to [pull in v3.2.0 of the Google Services plugin](https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-support-google-services/blob/master/build.gradle#L9), which also indirectly references the Play Services library.

TL;DR: you need to make `cordova-plugin-googleplus` specify the same version of the Play Services library as `phonegap-plugin-push`.

If you were building locally, you could use [cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release) to do this:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release  --variable PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION=11.6.2
```

However, you're building with Phonegap Build which [doesn't support the execution of hooks scripts](https://github.com/phonegap/build/issues/425) on which `cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release` relies.

So your best solution is probably to fork `cordova-plugin-googleplus` and set the Play Services version to `11.6.2` in `plugin.xml`, then use that fork in your build.

Comment: Ok Dave, thanks will do it and come back to you :) and let you konw

Comment: Can you also provide me with the steps to build locally

Comment: I have forked the plugin but now how do I use it in my config.xml ? Do I need to upload it on npm ?

Comment: `>Do I need to upload it on npm?` no just reference it directly from github in your config.xml: `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-googleplus" source="git" spec="https://github.com/yourGithubUsername/cordova-plugin-googleplus"></plugin>`

Comment: `>Can you also provide me with the steps to build locally`. See `https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html` and `https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html`

Comment: Thanks a lot dave . You saved my day :) my job as well